# Django Oauth2 Toolkit read access token from request body not headers

Tags: django, oauth

I have setup an OAuth2 provider using Django Oauth Toolkit, and it works fine. The issue is that the Client which is making requests to my API does not pass the access token in the headers (No "AUTHORIZATION : BEARER XXXXXXX"). Instead, the access token is passed in JSON data.

How can I change the toolkit's behaviour to read the access token from the data ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to satisfy OAuth toolkit's requirements by writing my own Django Middleware.

```
import json


class TokenMiddlewareFix(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        try:
            body = json.loads(request.body)
            token = body.get("accessToken", None)
            if token is not None:
                request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Bearer {}".format(token)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```